# MySQL Large Table Sharding to Smaller Table based on Unique ID

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

We have a large MySQL table (device_data) with the following columns:

```
ID (int)
dt (timestamp)
serial_number (char(20))
data1 (double)
data2 (double)
... // other columns
```

The table receives around 10M rows every day.

We have done a sharding by separating the table based on **the date of the timestamp (device_data_YYYYMMDD)**. However, we feel this is not effective because most of our queries (shown below) always check on the "serial_number" and will perform across many dates.

```
SELECT * FROM device_data WHERE serial_number = 'XXX' AND dt >= '2018-01-01' AND dt <= '2018-01-07';
```

Therefore, we think that creating the sharding based on **the serial number** will be more effective. Basically, we will have:

```
device_data_<serial_number>
device_data_0012393746
device_data_7891238456
```

Hence, when we want to find data for a particular device, we can easily reference as:

```
SELECT * FROM device_data_<serial_number> WHERE dt >= '2018-01-01' AND dt <= '2018-01-07';
```

This approach seems to be effective because:

1. The application at all time will access the data based on the device first.
2. We have checked that there is no query that access the data without specifying the device serial number first.
3. The table for each device will be relatively small (9000 rows per day)

A few challenges that we think we will face is:

1. We have alot of devices. This means that the table device_data_ will be alot too. I have checked that MySQL does not provide limitation in the number of tables in the database. Will this impact on performance vs keeping them in one table?
2. How will this impact on later on when we would like to scale MySQL (e.g. using master / slave, etc)?
3. Are there other alternative / solution in resolving this?

Update. Below is the show create table result from our existing table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_udp_new` (
 `id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `dt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `device_sn` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `gps_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `lat` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lng` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `device_sn_2` (`dt`,`device_sn`),
 KEY `dt` (`dt`),
 KEY `data` (`data`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `test_udp_new_device_sn_dt_index` (`device_sn`,`dt`),
 KEY `test_udp_new_device_sn_data_dt_index` (`device_sn`,`data`,`dt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44449751 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

The most frequent queries being run:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  test_udp_new
    WHERE  device_sn = 'xxx'
      AND  dt >= 'xxx'
      AND  dt <= 'xxx'
    ORDER BY  dt DESC;
```

Comment: Have you considered partitioning by serial? Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html

Comment: @fifonik - "serial"??  What is that?  [_This_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-types.html) shows the types, but the only useful one is `BY RANGE`.

Comment: Let's check some more things -- How much RAM?  How many GB in the table now?  How many when you stop gathering data?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: I meant `PARTITION BY HASH(func())`. In simplest case func might be crc32(left(serial_number, 10)) or something more useful which I cannot suggest because I do not know your serial numbers format. Anyway, I would not do the sharding as it might be a pain to support millions of tables later on (imaging you'd like to add/alter column there or get data for multiple serials in one query).

Comment: @RickJames right now we are setting around 12GB RAM out of 16GB. This easily becomes full when the table reaches around 100M rows and the table size reaches around 10GB (i.e. innodb_buffer_pool_size starting to get used up).

Comment: @HeruS - With proper indexing, I would not worry about even 100GB of data+indexes with only 12GB of buffer_pool.  It is a _cache_, so the trick is to avoid table/index scans.

Comment: Perhaps one of those was `dt <=`?

Comment: Yes you are right. I have changed this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The optimal way to handle *that* query is in a non-partitioned table with

```
INDEX(serial_number, dt)
```

Even better is to change the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Assuming you currently have `id AUTO_INCREMENT` because there is not a unique combination of columns suitable for being a "natural PK",

```
PRIMARY KEY(serial_number, dt, id),  -- to optimize that query
INDEX(id)  -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

If there are other queries that are run often, please provide them; this may hurt them.  In large tables, it is a juggling task to find the optimal index(es).

Other Comments:

- There are very few use cases for which partitioning actually speed up processing.
- Making lots of 'identical' tables is a maintenance nightmare, and, again, not a performance benefit.  There are probably a hundred Q&A on stackoverflow shouting not to do such.
- By having `serial_number` *first* in the `PRIMARY KEY`, all queries referring to a single serial_number are likely to benefit.
- A million `serial_numbers`?  No problem.
- One common use case for partitioning involves purging "old" data.  This is because big `DELETEs` are much more costly than `DROP PARTITION`.  That involves `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(dt))`.  If you are interested in that, my PK suggestion still stands.  (And the query in question will run about the same speed with or without this partitioning.)
- How many months before the table outgrows your disk?  (If this will be an issue, let's discuss it.)
- Do you need 8-byte `DOUBLE`?  `FLOAT` has about 7 significant digits of precision and takes only 4 bytes.
- You *are* using InnoDB?
- Is `serial_number` fixed at 20 characters?  If not, use `VARCHAR`.  Also, `CHARACTER SET ascii` may be better than the default of utf8?
- Each table (or each partition of a table) involves at least one file that the OS must deal with.  When you have "too many", the OS groans, often before MySQL groans.  (It is hard to make either "die" of overdose.)

Comment: I believe partitioning by serial_number would increase queries execution time (benchmarks required). "Some advantages of partitioning are listed here: - Some queries can be greatly optimized in virtue of the fact that data satisfying a given WHERE clause can be stored only on one or more partitions, which automatically excludes any remaining partitions from the search." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html

Comment: Agree on advice for decreasing row storage requirements as much as possible (using varchar with collation for serials, float).

Comment: @fifonik - A generalization:  Without an adequate index, partition pruning can provide a noticeable performance improvement.  With an adequate index, partition pruning is likely to slow down performance slightly.  You have an adequate index: any index starting with `(serial_number, dt)`.  The manual tends to specify _what_ you can do, not _whether_ to do it.

Comment: @fifonik - Another point:  When switching to (or from) Partitioning, all indexes need to be re-thought.  The best index(es) for one case are likely to be poor for the other.

Comment: @fifonik - If you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, I may have further tips on decreasing the disk footprint for the table and its indexes.  Oh, and, Partitioned tables inherently take extra space.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot provide `SHOW CREATE ...` results as I'm not O.P :)

Comment: We used to have index with serial_number and dt. But, it is starting to take a toll when the total rows in the table reaches around 100M (because it cannot fit into the innodb_buffer_pool). Therefore, we break it further by separating identical tables into device_data_YYYYMMDD.

Comment: I guess what I am concerned is that every query to `device_data` table always has the `serial_number` as the condition. Hence, I am thinking why can't we just use device_data_<serial_number> to store all the data in there. And, when we are querying a data from a certain serial number, we will just reference SELECT * FROM device_data_<serial_number>. With this, we will cut down the process of searching through the index and the table rows will be very much smaller. Of course, this in compensation in having MANY TABLES.

Comment: @HeruS - Do _not_ make lots of identical tables; it makes your code more complex and not necessarily any more efficient.  Ditto for using `PARTITIONing`.  Please provide the current `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  And provide the set of important `SELECTs`.  We can't design the optimal table and optimal indexes without having all the "cards on the table".

Comment: @RickJames I have added the show create table query and the most frequently used query. Look forward to your recommendation on this.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the query

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `device_sn_2` (`dt`,`device_sn`),
 KEY `dt` (`dt`),
 KEY `data` (`data`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `test_udp_new_device_sn_dt_index` (`device_sn`,`dt`),
 KEY `test_udp_new_device_sn_data_dt_index` (`device_sn`,`data`,`dt`)
```

-->

```
 PRIMARY KEY(`device_sn`,`dt`, id),
 INDEX(id)
 KEY `dt_sn` (`dt`,`device_sn`),
 KEY `data` (`data`) USING BTREE,
```

Notes:

- By starting the PK with `device_sn, dt`, you get the clustering benefits to make the query with `WHERE device_sn = .. AND dt BETWEEN ...`
- `INDEX(id)` is to keep `AUTO_INCREMENT` happy.
- When you have `INDEX(a,b)`, `INDEX(a)` is redundant.
- The `(20)` is meaningless; `id` will max out at about 4 billion.
- I tossed the last index because it is probably helped enough by the new PK.
- `lng decimal(10,5)` -- Don't need 5 decimal places to left of point; only need 3 or 2.  So:  `lat decimal(7,5),`lng decimal(8,5)`.  This will save a total of 3 bytes per row.

Comment: CMIIW making `device_sn`, `dt` as a PK instead of just an index will be more effective than partitioning based on `device_sn`? Assuming if I will have many queries running with conditional device_sn and dt.

Comment: @HeruS - Very likely that the PK will be better than partitioning.  In particular, the one query you provided will run better with the PK.  If you wish to provide examples of the queries; we can discuss further.